# Why gets `p` appended to new line although `display-inline`?

Tags: html, css

I have this simple html markup:

```
<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-index="0">
    Daddy, Yankee
    <p class="zumba">
        1996-03-14
    </p>
</div>
.....
```

So my aim is to have the `<p>` with the `class="zumba"` in the same line like the text `Daddy, Yankee` but on the right site:

I added `float-right` to align it a the right site, what worked out. But somehow its displayed in a new row!

Then i added:

```
.zumba {float:right; display:inline}
```

But the problem stays! Why? Thanks and here you can test you ideas:
http://jsfiddle.net/kMuA6/

Comment: Have you tried giving width?

Comment: I try to avoid this! Because i would like it to have it 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating elements always make them display:block, no matter what you define. (check firebug or any other developer tools for the value of display) Do you have control over the markup? Then wrap the "Daddy, Yankee"-text in an extra element and let it float left.

Comment: In what element would you wrap "Daddy Yankee"? Thanks

Comment: span probably as you just need it to apply style to it

Comment: "Floating elements always make them display:block". Almost, but not quite. `display:inline-table;` becomes `display:table` - `display:list-item` stays `display:list-item`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo for precise details.

Comment: you are totally right, I was just referring to inline elements as used in this special case :)

Answer (score 3):

Change yout `<p>` to `span`

**HTML**

```
<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-index="0">
    Daddy, Yankee <span class="zumba"> 1996-03-14 </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.zumba {float:right;}
```

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/drLbx/

**General Tip**: If its not much of a text, `<span>` is always a better option to show in same line (and different style)!! :)

Comment: you would need to remove your white-space: nowrap; then it works

Answer (score 2):

They have top and bottom margin. This works:

```
.zumba {float:right; display:inline; margin:0;}
```

Comment: yep, or just use `<span>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this whitout using any float.

It will work with < P > and < SPAN >.

```
<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-index="0">
    Daddy, Yankee
    <span class="zumba">
        1996-03-14
    </span>
</div>
```

I've add some color to identify.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kMuA6/2/

Answer (score 0):

try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kMuA6/1/

I just used `<span>` instead of `<p>`